# Google Cloud Run: Webhook POST causes 400 Response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigcommerce, google-cloud-run

We are catching a BigCommerce webhook event in our Google Cloud Run application. The request looks like:

#### Headers

```
host: abc-123-ue.a.run.app
AccountId: ABC
Content-Type: application/json
Password: Goodbye
Platform: BC
User-Agent: akka-http/10.1.10
Username: Hello
Content-Length: 197
Connection: keep-alive
```

#### Body

```
{"created_at":1594914374,"store_id":"1001005173","producer":"stores/gy68868uk5","scope":"store/product/created","hash":"139fab64ded23b3e1b8473ba24ab21bedd3f535b","data":{"type":"product","id":132}}
```

For some reason, this causes a 400 response from Google Cloud Run. Our application doesn't even seem to be passed the request. All other endpoints work (including other post requests).

Any ideas?

#### Edit

In the original post, I had the path in the host header. This was a mistake made in creating this post and not the actual value passed to us. We can only inspect the request via Requestbin (I can't find the request values anywhere in Google logs) so I'm speculating on the host value and made a mistake writing it out here.

#### Research so far...

So upon further testing, it seems that BigCommerce Webhooks also fail to send to any Google Cloud Function we set up. As a workaround, I'm having Pipedream catch the webhook and send the payload to our application. No problems there. This endpoint also works with mirror payloads from local and Zapier which seems to eliminate authentication errors.

We are running FastAPI on Google Run and the simplest function on Google Cloud Functions. This seems to be an error with how Google Serverless and BigCommerce Webhook Events communicate with each other. I'm just not sure how...

#### Here are the headers we managed to capture on one of the only times a BigCommerce Webhook Event came through to our Google Cloud Function:

```
Content-Length: 197
Content-Type: application/json
Host: us-central1-abc-123.cloudfunctions.net
User-Agent: akka-http/10.1.10
Forwarded: for="0.0.0.0";proto=https
Function-Execution-Id: unes7v34vzyo
X-Appengine-Country: ZZ
X-Appengine-Default-Version-Hostname: f696ddc1d56c3fd66p-tp.appspot.com
X-Appengine-Https: on
X-Appengine-Request-Log-Id: 5f10e15c00ff082ecbb02ee3a70001737e6636393664646331643536633366643636702d7470000165653637393633633164376565323033383131366437343031613365613263303a36000100
X-Appengine-Timeout-Ms: 599999
X-Appengine-User-Ip: 0.0.0.0
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: a62207698d141465d0f38488492d088b/9870406606828581415
X-Forwarded-For: 0.0.0.0
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close
```

Comment: Did you check "allow unauthenticated invocations" when you created the cloud run service?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll add more information to the post

Answer (score 0):

```
> host: abc-123-ue.a.run.app/bigcommerce/webhooks/
```

This is most likely the issue. `Host` headers must contain only the hostname, not the request /paths.

You can clearly see this will fail:

```
$ curl -IvH 'Host: pdf-2wvlk7vg3a-uc.a.run.app/foo' https://pdf-2wvlk7vg3a-uc.a.run.app
...
HTTP/2 400
```

However if you don't craft the `Host` header yourself, it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We do not craft the event request ourselves, and this was a mistake only in creating this post. I have edited the original question to reflect your comment.

Comment: Well that kinda changes everything. You need to provide debug info on "what works" and "when things stop working". It could be a header, could be how you make the request. Please include as much detail as possible. I'm guessing right now, nobody here can look at your question and provide an answer.